# Setup static member object

Tags: c++

Maybe this question has been asked around but I couldn't find it. **How do I setup a static member object at its creation?** And possibly perform some other tasks. The goal is to have some of it's setters called at it's creation time.

Example:

Header file A.h:

```
class A{

public:
    A::A();
    ~A::A();
    static QTimer updateTimer;

};
```

Expected implementation file A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

QTimer A::updateTimer.setInverval(100); // I need to set it's inverval to 100ms 
   // but only once in the beginning of it's life time

A::A(){...
}

~A::A(){...
}
```

So, as you can see, I would like to call 'setInverval()' function of my static object only once at it's creation and not have it called every time a new 'A' object is created.

Comment: @Bathsheba: If nothing else I'd find that confusing and suspicious as a later reader of the code, unless it were accompanied by a big FO comment explanation. Prefer to avoid, IMO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I may... "FO" ?

Comment: @Quentin: "frak off" and so on e.g. http://www.scotranslate.com/translate/scottish/big-fuck-off-rock/1/67321#.V63N37grJZo Slightly corrupted US usage documented here: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fuck%20off%20big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what constructors are for.

If it's your own type, just write a constructor.

If the type doesn't have a constructor and you cannot modify it (like, presumably `QTimer` comes from Qt), then wrap it in a type of your own that does. This is a textbook case of inheritance being useful. Your wrapper class will extend the original class with a bit of new functionality: setting the interval during initialisation.

```
struct QTimerWrapper : QTimer
{
   QTimerWrapper(int interval)
   {
      setInterval(interval);
   }
};

struct A
{
    static QTimerWrapper updateTimer;
};

QTimerWrapper A::updateTimer(100);
```

Or you could use composition, having the `QTimer` be a member of `QTimerWrapper` instead.

Comment: All answers seem to solve my problem, but this one seems to target the desired behavior without many side effects. Also I chose it for the sake of generality of my question, so it stays pertinent to others.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to composition or inheritance, you can also create a function which returns the modified object

```
QTimer newTimerWithInterval(int interval){
  QTimer timer;
  timer.setInteval(interval);
  return timer;
}

QTimer A::updateTimer(newTimerWithInterval(100));
```

You might want to put the function under local `namespace` as you do not probably need it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this? pseudocode:

```
class A { static shared_ptr<Timer> _timer; };
..
A::A()
{
   if (_timer == nullptr)
   {
      _timer.assign(new Timer);
      _timer->setInterval(100);
   }
}
```

---

or if you don't need to manage this timer or have any dynamic objects - then you can use statically made inner object:

```
class A { /* without static member */ };
A::A
{
  static bool timerInited = false;
  static QTimer timer;
  if (!timerInited)
  {
     timer.setInterval(100);
     timerInited = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for dynamic allocation. Also now `A` is responsible for a behaviour of the timer, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: it actually depends on what you expect from this timer-object. you can also use non-member static object like this:
class A {};  
A::A() { static unique_ptr<QTimer> timer; if (timer == nullptr) ..... etc

Comment: so just call this member function globally:
A::updateTimer.setInterval(100);

Comment: but don't forget that global objects initialization is unordered

Comment: I thought of your second option, with `timerInited`, and indeed was going to do it. But still seems less appropriate to have more variables to implement this.

Comment: well, bool variable is a less evil than creating subclass :)
actually you can modify Lightness Races in Orbit answer and mix with this one - you can make static object of QTimerWrapper inside the constructor. so you don't need any bool intermediate variables.

Comment: _"but don't forget that global objects initialization is unordered"_ Only partially

Comment: their partiality doesn't matter in this case